# Node cron only excute specified date and stop completely after excute success

Tags: node.js, cron-task, node-cron

I have this code:

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

  var task = cron.schedule('0 36 17 10 SEP 4 2020', () =>  {
    console.log('will execute');
});
```

This code run `console.log('will execute')` at 17:00:00 10 Sep 2020 and I run success.
But I think process not stop when after excute success.

Anyone help me stop process completely after excute success?

Thanks!